# AWS availability zone logical or physical?

Tags: amazon-web-services

quoting AWS:

> AWS has the concept of a Region, which is a physical location around the world where we cluster data centers. We call each group **of logical data centers an Availability Zone**. Each AWS Region consists of **multiple, isolated, and physically separate AZs within a geographic area**.

I'm confused by the meaning of "logical data centers" here: if AZ are physically separated data centers, I would assume the ressources are physical too, wouldn't be more appropriate to say "physical data centers"? or maybe am I wrong on the definition of logical here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS availability zone logical or physical?

> When they say logical datacenter it's like saying a logical model
> which describes the physical datacenter without regarding to how they
> are physically implemented, but giving you a clear perspective how
> they operate.

In contrast, a physical datacenter is like model that represents how the actual datacenter is implemented.
Hence, this is the main difference between logical and physical.
But the two terminologies are used interchangeably a little bit.

**That being said, we use logical when we are designing/describing the architecture of the physical model**

Comment: exactly the subtlety I wanted to clear out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An Availability Zone (AZ) is one or more discrete data centers with redundant power, networking, and connectivity in an AWS Region.

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/